# Creating a service in Alpine Linux to run Java application

Tags: services, daemon, alpine-linux

I would like to deploy a spring boot application into a docker container. I had created the base image using `Alpine Linux`. My old configuration runs a service on `Red Hat` under this path `/etc/systemd/system/service.service`.

I am wondering if this is a good approach to create the service into the container or leave the management responsibility of the service to the Docker composer.

Here is the service in Redhat:

```
[Unit]
 Description=service description

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=dir
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "java -Xmx512m -jar ms-service-0.0.1.jar"
Restart=on-failure
[Install]
```

I have in my Dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Xmx512m","-jar","/usr/src/service/ms-service-0.0.1.jar"]
```

Comment: If you are moving your application into Docker, as I think you are suggesting you are doing, then you use a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` to start the application. As I understand it, the application must be PID 1, and the application must not exit (until desired). So you would not use a `service` inside of Docker. Docker will start/stop the container, and the container should only execute the application.